# What process should nagios look for to check IIS7 running status?

Tags: iis-7, nagios

We're finally rolling out Server 2008 systems and our old IIS6 check looked for IIS.exe, which doesn't appear to be used anymore. **Is there a better process name to look for?**

We already have network availability checks in place, but having multiple forms of checks like this helps diagnose where not to look.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at one of my own systems, as long as your site has traffic, it seems like you should have at least one w3wp.exe process running, spawned from svchost (command line: C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k iissvcs). It doesn't look like any w3wp.exe processes start until you get at least one hit.

I'm assuming you're also checking to see if the service itself is started, which I would think is a better check than just looking for an exe.

Comment: Right. I had tried w3wp.exe but the system is currently in preproduction. I'm setting up host checks while some other stuff comes into place. Even once in production, the traffic will be pretty much negligible at night.

Comment: Are you able to check arguments like the "-k iissvcs" in that command line? It seems like "svchost.exe -k iissvcs" runs two services: "Windows Process Activation Service" and WWW Publishing. Combined with checking the service status should verify IIS is running.

Comment: Also, if you're also running a check on port 80 to make sure IIS is responding, there should always be a w3wp.exe because it would have to be spawned for your port 80 check.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is better to check that it is responding to requests than the process itself. Check port 80 if it's listening on that, what if it locks up and IIS is running but not serving any pages?

Comment: We have HTTP checks on 80 and 443. Belt and suspenders.